# Limit width of title - Echarts

Tags: echarts

I need a limited width on echarts title as specified on [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#title.textStyle.width).
I set `textStyle` `rich` since is necessary to apply width but it does not work.

In this example I used the echarts demo.
The legend overlaps with the title despite the width set to 20%.

```js
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};
option = null;
app.title = '环形图';

option = {
    title: {
        text: "{aaa|Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}",  
        textStyle: {
            width: '20%',
            rich: {
                aaa: {
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    color: 'blue'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        data:['邮件营销','联盟广告']
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    grid: {
        left: '3%',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '3%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    xAxis : [
        {
            type : 'category',
            boundaryGap : false,
            data : ['周一','周二']
        }
    ],
    yAxis : [
        {
            type : 'value'
        }
    ],
    series : [
        {
            name:'邮件营销',
            type:'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data:[120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
        },
        {
            name:'联盟广告',
            type:'line',
            stack: '总量',
            areaStyle: {},
            data:[220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
        }
    ]
};

if (option && typeof option === "object") {
    myChart.setOption(option, true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0.rc2/echarts.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.1.0/echarts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Maybe a bug so I created an [Github Issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/9311)

Comment: There is an example at https://codepen.io/bantaur/pen/PyrJBb. Stackoverflow snippet is too long and I get an error (It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details)